# How to write and calculate Sum/ Product (of a function) in R

Tags: r, sum

Assuming that I have a function, let's say `f(x)`.

How can I write the product or sum of this function for given limits in x.

For instance product of `f` for `x=1` until `x=5`
`f(1)*f(2)*f(3)*f(4)*f(5)`

Additionally I need to figure this out for sums/double sums.
Consider `f(x,y)` and the sum while x runs from 1 to 3 and y runs from 0 to x-1.
If written in mathematica, it would be this:
`Sum[f[x, y], {x, 1, 3}, {y, 0, x - 1}]`
and the output would be this
`f[1, 0] + f[2, 0] + f[2, 1] + f[3, 0] + f[3, 1] + f[3, 2]`

`f` is not defined for simplicity.

EDIT: example as requested:

```
f <- function (x,y) { 
x + 2*y 
}
```

Calculate sum where x runs from 1 to 3 and y runs from 0 to x-1. 
(this is equal to 22 btw)

Comment: Please show a reproducible example

Comment: Please do define `f`. If `f` is vectorized, you could simply do `sum(f(1:5))`. If it is not, you could either vectorize it or use a for loop.

Comment: @Vandenman let's say for simplicity that `f <- function(x) { x+x^2}`

Comment: that function is vectorized, so you could do `f <- function(x) x + x^2; sum(f(1:5))`.

Comment: ok, but what about product or having double sum, where one variable is defined based on the other variable, as showed in my question. Let's condider : `f <- function (x,y) { x + 2*y }` and I need to calculate sum where x runs from 1 to 3 and y runs from 0 to x-1. (this is equal to 22 btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
f <- function (x,y) { 
  x + 2*y 
}
)

#calculate f for all combinations
tmp <- outer(1:3, 0:2, f)

#discard undesired combinations and sum
sum(tmp[lower.tri(tmp, diag = TRUE)])
#[1] 22
```

Alternatively you can use a loop to create the desired combinations only. This is much slower:

```
inds <- lapply(1:3, function(x) data.frame(x = x, y = 0:(x-1)))
inds <- do.call(rbind, inds)
sum(do.call(f, inds))
#[1] 22
```